# Let a left div vanish at the browsers borders (like you already can with the right side)

Tags: css, html

I made a sketch for my site, please see on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4GDP/).

The HTML:

```
<div id="BG-scroll">
    <div id="faders">
        <div id="links"></div>
        <div id="filler"></div>
        <div id="rechts"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```css
#BG-scroll {
    width: 100%;
    height: 503px;
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(images/BG-container-1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}   

#wrapper {
    width: 650px;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: green;
}   

#faders {
    height: 200px;
    width: 950px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#left {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
}

#filler {
    width: 650px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
}

#right {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

What I want is the blue and the green divs centered on the browser. In the red and pink left and right divs there will be 2 image slideshows (for in the background) In the wrapper is the main site.

Is it possible in CSS to center the 2 middle divs and give the left and right div a fixed width (300px) -> and when the browser is smaller that the left div will move out of the browser (like you can with rescaling the browser for the right side of the site. Now the left side of the red div stays always in the left side of the browser.

Is that even possible in CSS? The Joomla module for the slideshow left and right generates divs to put the slideshow in.

Comment: What red and pink divs?  http://cssdeck.com/labs/kqylf5xf

Comment: Can you tell us which browser you're testing your code in, please ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a [media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to remove the div. Something like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
    #div{
         display:none;
    }
}
```

Once the browser reaches 300px wide then the div will change style to whatever you set under the media query.

I'm not too sure what you're asking with the rest of the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with cimmanon, there is no red and pink divs in the code. However, generally if you wish to have some element "move out of the browser" when reducing the width of the browser, you could use this CSS style:

```
position: absolute;
right: ***px;
```

You probably have to calculate the actual right position by yourself since the flow of html elements normally runs from left-top to bottom-right. Making flow reversed (right to left) is not easy and may not be recommended.

Here is the possible [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/E4GDP/1/) for your question.